# My visual studio won't connect to local database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, localdb

I am following [this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model) simple MVC tutorial (Visual Studio) and there is no database created in `App_Data`. I think it might have to do with my installing mySQL, but I uninstalled it and it still doesn't work.

This message pops up when I reopen my Visual Studio

> The Web project "project" requires SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB, which is not installed on this computer. To upgrade the project datbase to use latest SQL Server Express LocalDB...

I tried googling that message and tried a lot of different things, I even reinstalled Visual Studio. I have Visual Studio 2015.

This is the error message when I try to run the page "/movies"

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 18:         public ActionResult Index()
>   Line 19:         {
>   Line 20:             return View(db.Movies.ToList());
>   Line 21:         }
>   Line 22: "

Comment: Could show your LocalDb connection string?

Comment: sorry , I am brand new. How do I show that? I think it's MSSQLLocalDB?

Comment: It will be in **Web.config** file. What's it showing between the `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>` tags?

Comment: oh I was following [this](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model) tutorial.  So I added 

<add name="MovieDBContext" 
   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
/>

Comment: See [this on how to connect to `localdb` for `sql server express localdb 2014 ++`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41708748/304683)

Comment: @EdSF that worked! you rock, thank you so much.